# How to solve Circular navigation problem or Back Loop problem in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have this problem. I can not exit the app in the MainPage.

I started navigating from MainPage --> Page 2 ---> Page 3.

In Page3, I use navigationService to go to MainPage.  Can someone help me on this?

Also I am abit confused on this term e.cancel = true or false in  override the BackKeyPress Event.

1.)   e.Cancel = true  means Cancel moving back ? or cancel what?
2) e.cancel = false ,?

3) Do I need to override the backKey press in MainPage?

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

            if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Cancel = true; // yes cancel the default behavior ??
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

3) any workaround solution for this probem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need the [Non-Linear Navigation Service](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7).

It was designed for just this situation. Just navigate from Page3 back to the MainPage and it takes care of sorting out the back stack for you. There is no need to manually trigger extra calls to `GoBack()`, etc.